# Cordova plugin with Capacitor and Quasar

Tags: vue.js, barcode-scanner, capacitor, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm building an app with Quasar and Capacitor.
I'd like to use `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`(or is there any other option for QR reading?).
I've installed plugin with `npm i phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` to src-capacitor project. What's my next steps, do I need to register it in `capacitor.config`?
How do I call `scan` function on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out. You need to run `npx cap sync` in `src-capacitor` folder. And than the plugin accessible via `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner` like it was previously with Cordova